# How to join two or more DataFrames in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas

I've trying to join 3 dataframes, however I'm having problems to do it.  Let me show the scenario.

I have 3 dataframes:

First: **Country**

just two columns: **Country_ID, Country_Name**
Primary Key: **Country_ID**

**Country_ID** | **Country_Name**

```
BR     |   Brazil
```

Second: **Sports**

just three columns: **Country ID, Sport_ID, Sport_Name**
Primary Key: **Country_ID, Sport_ID**

**Country_ID** | **Sport_ID**| **Sport_Name**

```
BR         |    1234     |     Football
```

Third: **University**

just four columns: **Country_ID, University_ID, University_Name**
Primary Key: **Country_ID, University_ID**

**Country_ID** | **University_ID**| **University_Name**

```
BR         |    UFCABC        | Federal University of ABC
```

Final Result: just these columns: **Country_Name, Sport_Name, University_Name**

**Country_Name** | **Sport_Name** | **University_Name**

Brazil     |  Football  |  Federal university of Brazil

I tried to join ContryXSport and after that with university DataFrame, however I wasn't able to do it.

Here is the code for creation and join the dataframes:

```
country_raw_data = {
            'country_id': [country.id for country in countries],
            'country_name': [country.name for country in countries]                                  }

sport_raw_data = {
            'country_id': [sport.country.id for sport in sports],                
            'sport_id': [sport.id for sport in sports],
            'sport_name': [sport.name for sport in sports]
        }

university_raw_data = {
            'country_id': [university.country.id for university in universities],                
            'university_id': [university.state.id for university in universities],
            'university_name': [university.name for university in universities]
        }
```

Now, the dataframe instances:

I tried to create df like this:

```
country_df = pd.DataFrame(country_raw_data, columns: ['country_id', 'country_name'])
```

I don't know why, the country_df was create wrong, some columns didn't appear correct with the right values. Then I had to create like this, it is working.

```
country_df = pd.DataFrame(country_raw_data) 
sport_df = pd.DataFrame(sport_raw_data) 
university_df = pd.DataFrame(university_raw_data)
```

Here, is the joins declarations:

I tried to do like this, however the result didn't join correct. Some columns didn't include the data frame correctly.

```
country_state_df = pd.merge(country_df, state_df, on='country_id', how='inner')
```

Another code tht I did it, however I had the same problem before:

```
country_sport_df = pd.merge(country_df, sport_df, 
                        left_on='country_id', 
                        right_on='sport_id', 
                        how='inner')
```

So, after the first join, I did the next join between country_state with city

```
country_sport_university.df = pd.merge(country_sport_df, university_df, 
                             on=['country_id', 'country_id'], 
                             how='inner')
```

I'd like the final result must be like these columns:

**country_name** | **Sport_Name** | **University_Name**

Brazil     | Football   | Federal University of ABC

it is possible to do it using dataframe, or I need to use another libraries?

So, there are a lot of data, around millions of data, for example.

Can anyone help my or give me a suggestion to solve the problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example with your 3 dataframes? You could attach `country_df.head(5)` and for other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to:

```
country_sport_df = country_df.merge(sport_df, on='country_id', how='inner')
country_university_df = university_df.merge(sport_df, on='country_id', how='inner').drop(['country_id', 'sport_id', 'university_id'], axis=1)
```

I assume that it's on purpose that `country_id` is the only link between `sport_id` and `university_id`.

Comment: I didn't realize you could chain drop. Would this prevent the suffixes for common columns?

Comment: Stefan, thank you for helping me. It's working now. I found a good documentation about this: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)